# Multi task classification CNN

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i have a df which is constructed like this, i have 5 columns and i have to perform a multi task or multi output classification

```
Daytime     Environment   Filename      Weather     
day         wet           2018-10.png   light_fog   [Example of one row]
```

my problem is when i have done the flow from dataframe, i don't know how to use tf.data.dataset in order to build the dataset. Someone suggest me to use TFRecords but i have never used it. How can i do without using it?

```
train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_gen = train_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(train_df,
                                               directory=dataset_dir,
                                               x_col="Filename",
                                               y_col=["Daytime", "Weather", "Environment"],
                                               class_mode="multi_output",
                                               target_size=(img_size, img_size),
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               shuffle=True,
                                               seed=SEED)
```

Comment: I believe you can create tf.data.Dataset directly from DataFrame without using ImageDataGenerator. See the following article: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe#with_tfdata

Comment: But i didn't get how i can deal with multiple outputs through tf.data.Dataset

Comment: See my answer and let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe#with_tfdata), you should be able to do something similar:

```
filenames = df.pop('Filename')
feature_names = ["Daytime", "Weather", "Environment"]
features = df[numeric_feature_names]

shuffle_buffer_size = len(df.index) # Or whatever shuffle size you want to use
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, features))
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
# Performs the function for each pair of a filename and its corresponding features
ds = ds.map(prepare_image) 
dataset = ds.batch(batch_size)
# Prefetch is just for optimization
dataset = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=1)

def prepare_image(filepath, features):
    # You can do whatever transformations in here.
    file_content = tf.io.read_file(image_file_path)
    image = tf.io.decode_png(file_content)
    return image, features
```

Note that this should just give you the idea. I did not test it, so it may throw an error or two.